# Graphing a function of an input output exchange

Tags: java

Is there a way to graph the values outputted by the following code in a separate class.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class scannerNumber {
    public static void main(String []args) {

    Scanner originalNumber = new Scanner(System.in); // number for input

    System.out.println("Enter a number: "); // asks for input

    int firstNumber = originalNumber.nextInt();

    double secondNumber = Math.abs((firstNumber*Math.sin(firstNumber)));

    System.out.println("Your new number is: " + secondNumber);

    originalNumber.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: I don't see why anyone is downvoting or upvoting, just make a comment or answer. Im rather new to java so it doesn't help, its rather disruptive actually.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I think you got downvoted because you're asking a question without showing what you've tried so far to make it work yourself, or what specific difficulties you're facing. Don't let the downvotes deter you. If you've tried something out, edit your post to include it, even if it doesn't work. It's easier sometimes to fix the errors in broken code, than having strangers write all the code for you.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I do not have other code for this, as I have no clue how to approach it at all though. But thanks for the information, I'll keep it in mind for future questions. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Scanner originalNumber = new Scanner(System.in); // number for input

ArrayList<Double> results = new ArrayList<Double>;// array for results

System.out.println("Enter a number: "); // asks for input

int firstNumber = originalNumber.nextInt();

for(int i=0; i<=firstNumber; i++){
    double secondNumber = Math.abs((firstNumber*Math.sin(firstNumber)));

    results.add(secondNumber);//add results to an array
}
for(int k:results)
    System.out.print(k+" ");

originalNumber.close();
```

this will create an array that contains y values while x is between [0,firstNumber]
*note that this not a complete answer for your question. you should start with basics.*
[complete tutorial for function drawing in java](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Advanced-Graphics/Drawthefunction.htm)
. you can use this tutorial but first look at gui for java.

Comment: Thanks so much! :)